# During Magento 2.1.12 Product Export,some attribute values for english store missing

Tags: export, magento2.1.12

There are 2700 products on the site & lots of product custom attributes.I've 2 stores **"default"** & **"english"** & when I'm exporting products then getting empty values for the store "english" in most of the attributes columns.

**e.g-**"name","description","custom-attribute" etc.

Please see the screenshot:-

[image]

I've already done reindexing,ignore customs attributes during export etc.

Please help me to resolve this issue **ASAP**.

--
Thanks!!!